# In Android6.0，How to make the navigation translucent when screenOrientation="landscape"

Tags: android, navigation

in `onCreate()`,i use the `FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS` and `FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION` make the navigation translucent.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);


}
```

My **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

it works in Android5.1.1, but it has no effect in Android 6.0.
when i set android:screenOrientation="portrait" ,it has useful in Android 6.0 .

effective?:

- Android5.1.1+portrait----------yes
- Android5.1.1+landscape-----yes
- Android6.0+portrait------------yes
- android6.0+landscape--------no

Answer (score 0):

You have add theme i suppose.

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

and also mention in your manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" 
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Try , If it helps.